# z-index to order divs doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, html, z-index

I have this page: http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/?q=specials_events no, if you however over Book now, the div to enter the booking details appears but the submit button stays behind the div with the content even tho I set the "fade" dive's z-index to 99. Why is that?

Thank you,
Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use z-index on `position: relative` or `position: absolute` elements. If you set your header to be position relative, it will fix the problem:

```
#HeaderBar {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#book{
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

This will solve the issue.